# Compare only today's date without hours/min/sec

Tags: python, time, compare

I want to compare todays time with another new time without hour/min or seconds. Ignore hour and minutes...

In other words if both days are the same no matter hours or minutes it is ok (Extra) otherwise it is not good (Too old)... I tried but even with the same day still continue to compare with hour/min and sec. How can I do it?

```
import datetime
currentdate = datetime.datetime.now()
print(currentdate)

newsdate = "Oct-26-2021"
newsdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(newsdate, "%b-%d-%Y")
print(newsdate)

if currentdate == newsdate:
    print("Extra")
else:
print("Too old")`
```

Comment: You can use `datetime.date.today()` to get today's date without a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare using only the *date* component of datetime, accessible via the  `.date()` attribute:

```py
import datetime
currentdate = datetime.datetime.now()
print(currentdate)

newsdate = "Oct-26-2021"
newsdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(newsdate, "%b-%d-%Y")
print(newsdate)

if currentdate.date() == newsdate.date():
    print("Extra")
else:
    print("Too old")
```

The above can also be reworded as follows (perhaps to aid in readability for others):

```py
from datetime import date, datetime

currentdate: date = date.today()
print(currentdate)

date_string = "Oct-26-2021"
newsdate: date = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%b-%d-%Y").date()
print(newsdate)

if currentdate == newsdate:
    print("Extra")
else:
    print("Too old")
```

Comment: @Leah no problem! Also feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if you found it helpful.